# Joomla toolbar for save, publish etc not appearing in admin

Tags: joomla

I have just installed Joomla 3.1.4 on my local PC. Everything seems fine and it installed successfully. However when I go into admin through Firefox it does not show the admin toolbar in the backend so after making changes I cannot save, publish etc. However when I go into the site through Chrome everything seems to work well and the toolbar appears. I cannot workout what is stopping Firefox from displaying the toolbar. I had installed the site a number of times so Firefox seems to remember something from my previous usage.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed some strangeness with this latest release, also. It may be an admin template bug. Try scrolling the page when you're ready to save.

Update: I just checked 2 of my J3! sites, and they seem ok. Maybe a cache issue?

Comment: I cleared out the complete cache of Firefox as suggested. It works now.